# Получаю лишний абзац текста с символом - как это исправить?

Tags: html, css, html5

Есть текст. После 4 строчки получаю лишний абзац текста с символом - как это исправить? (символ должен распространяться именно на этот большой абзац).

```css
p:before {
 content: "\f055";
 font-family: FontAwesome;
 margin-right: 10px;
 color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12">
<p>1 Бла-бла-бла</p>
<p>2 – Бла-бла-бла</p>
<p>3 - Бла-бла-бла</p>
<p>4 – Бла-бла-бла:
<ul><li>раз</li><li>два</li><li>три</li><li>четыре</li><li>пять</li></ul>
продолжение :) </p>
<p>5 – Бла-бла-бла</p>
</div>

Теперь уже за вопрос с примером минусуют?
```

Comment: за что столько минусов-то? с 2016 года за вопросы с примерами и желанием разобраться минусы ставят?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<p>4 – Бла-бла-бла:
  <ul>
    <li>раз</li>
    <li>два</li>
    <li>три</li>
    <li>четыре</li>
    <li>пять</li>
  </ul>
  продолжение :)</p>
```

из-за вот этого кода, так не оборачивают

```
<p>4 – Бла-бла-бла:
    <ul>
      <li>раз</li>
      <li>два</li>
      <li>три</li>
      <li>четыре</li>
      <li>пять</li>
    </ul>
    продолжение :) </p>
 <p>5 – Бла-бла-бла</p>
```

Элемент p не должен содержать блочные элементы.

Comment: Поясните, почему именно так не делают

Comment: Элемент <p> не должен содержать блочные элементы.

Comment: Добавьте это в свой ответ

Comment: переместите закрытие тега p после бла-бла-бла

Comment: @zorro вторая и самая главная часть вопроса: как исправить?

Comment: хотя бы так: <p>4 – Бла-бла-бла: </p>

Comment: @zorro ну и что это будет? вы видите у меня в стилях символ стоит (в данном случае плюс), т.е. мне нужно чтобы перед этим большим куском со списком стоял 1! плюс, а не 10

Comment: тогда делай через акордион

Comment: вообще вот этот код чудесно работает: https://jsfiddle.net/martynuk/xs2r6nLd/

Answer (score 2):

Элемент `<p>` не должен содержать блочные элементы. Вот и получается что перед открытием `<ul>` он закрывается.

Comment: вторая часть вопроса: как исправить?

Answer (score -3):

```
<div class="col-md-12">
                                        <p>1 Бла-бла-бла</p>
    <p>2 – Бла-бла-бла</p>
    <p>3 - Бла-бла-бла</p>
    <p>4 – Бла-бла-бла:</p>
    <span><ul><li>раз</li><li>два</li><li>три</li><li>четыре</li><li>пять</li></ul>
    продолжение :) </span>
    <p>5 – Бла-бла-бла</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: и, мне нужен большой абзац - как исправить - знаете?